# Matching against parts of a string

Tags: lua

I want to match a string against a "code" that may contain other letters.
Meaning the string is `***d*d**`, I want it to check from a list of names, like "Davida", "Deradedee", "Dascadadaa" and "Terdaded" and see in which one the actual letters match up, the * representing an unknown letter.  The stars can also be dashes or underscores.  Also, the original string is subject to change, sometimes it might be `S**ss*` and then it would need to match the name that is similar to that.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried regular expressions?

Comment: Replace stars with dots and use string.find: `if ("Terdaded"):find("^...d.d..$") then print"Found" end`

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do can be achieved using string patterns.

Please read [Lua 5.3 Reference Manual 6.4.1 - Patterns](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1)

You can use these patterns in functions like string.find or string.match.

See Egor's comment for an example on how to use them.